# SonarQube upgrade 5.6.5 to 6.7 fails with "Table 'perm_tpl_characteristics' already exists"

Tags: sonarqube

When upgrading SonarQube from v5.6.5 to V6.7, running `\setup` produced the following error:

```
2017.12.01 10:33:12 WARN  web[][o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
....
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.6.0 / 
....
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarTS / 1.1.0.1079 / 042c9e65239a47d92d305f9767f730b3cc1e5ed3
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Sonargraph / 3.5
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Sonargraph Integration / 2.0.1
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.5.0.476 / 636872f5d37fa7a440fe07d08d504e1a881225e5
2017.12.01 10:33:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin jDepend / 1.1.1
2017.12.01 10:33:13 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Database needs migration
2017.12.01 10:33:13 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@5851f091 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/system/migrate_db/*, ...], exclusions=[/api/properties*, ...]}]
2017.12.01 10:33:13 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.12.01 10:33:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] Starting DB Migration and container restart
2017.12.01 10:33:29 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executing DB migrations...
2017.12.01 10:33:29 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1200 'Create table PERM_TPL_CHARACTERISTICS'...
2017.12.01 10:33:29 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1200 'Create table PERM_TPL_CHARACTERISTICS': failure | time=12ms
2017.12.01 10:33:29 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=13ms
2017.12.01 10:33:29 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=57ms
2017.12.01 10:33:29 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1200 'Create table PERM_TPL_CHARACTERISTICS' failed
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:50)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doUpgradeDb(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doDatabaseMigration(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute CREATE TABLE perm_tpl_characteristics (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,template_id INTEGER NOT NULL,permission_key VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,with_project_creator TINYINT(1) DEFAULT false NOT NULL,created_at BIGINT NOT NULL,updated_at BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_perm_tpl_characteristics PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:97)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:117)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.version.v60.CreatePermTemplatesCharacteristics.execute(CreatePermTemplatesCharacteristics.java:48)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange.execute(DdlChange.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:75)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'perm_tpl_characteristics' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:82)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Is the upgrade from one LTS version to the next too much?   Should I upgrade to an intermediate version first?   If so, what would be the shortest upgrade path?

The various MySql versions are:

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.20                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1                |
| version                 | 5.7.20-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

The plugins between the v5.6.5 and v6.7 instances aren't 100% identical.  Some plugins are no longer supported in version 6.x.  Based on the error message, I don't think that's the issue, but it is a difference between the two configurations.

Comment: Upgrading from LTS to LTS is the way to go. No intermediate steps are required. Could you please restore your db backup and try again? If it fails again, please provide your MySQL version.

Comment: The stack trace above is the result of restoring the DB from a backup made from the 'production' (v5.6.5) SonarQube instance to a fresh copy of V6.7.  I installed the MySql, created the 'sonar' database and user with no issues.

Comment: Could you try it once again? I know it sounds silly, but sometimes it just works at the second try...

Comment: I sure will. Exporting from the prod instance and importing to the new one.

Comment: I ran through the process again:  Exported the database from the source server, copied the backup to the destination server, dropped and recreated the 'sonar' database on the destination server, imported the backup, restarted the server, ran `/update` again.  Same result.

Comment: Strange. The db migration consists of hundreds of steps, the first one tries to create a new table - and fails because that table already exists. It looks to me, like there has already been someone trying to migrate that db. Could it be, that your production db is "half"/unsuccessfully migrated?

Comment: PS: 5.6.7 is the latest 5.6 version. However I do not expect that to be the reason for your issues.

Comment: You're correct, after a successful upgrade from 5.6.5 to 5.6.7, I get the same error attempting to upgrade from 5.6.7 to 6.7.

Comment: I'm prototyping the upgrade process on a box where I've installed MySQL and SonarQube.  Everything is new and shiny, and I've consistently gotten the same error since I started.  Really struggling with this one.

Comment: I found one other post mentioning this [error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/N4ARDknpGHE).  I've asked for guidance there also.

Comment: I upgraded from v5.6.7 to v6.0 with no issues ('setup' reported the database was up to date), but the upgrade to v6.2 failed with the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was this database was initially created as part of a fresh V6.2 installation.  There was a problem with a plugin, so the installation was rolled back to v5.6.5.  I don't know if `/upgrade` had to be invoked during the 'downgrade'.  Either way, the upgrade process didn't expect this edge case, so I manually fixed it.

I ran the MySql query `show table status;` and it showed the `perm_tpl_characteristics` was empty, so I deleted it.  I re-ran the upgrade and another it failed with a similar error for another table.  I deleted tables and re-ran the upgrade until it was successful.  This is what I ended up with:

```
USE DATABASE sonar;
DROP TABLE perm_tpl_characteristics;
DROP TABLE ce_task_input;
DROP TABLE ce_scanner_context;
DROP TABLE internal_properties;
DROP TABLE qprofile_changes;
DROP TABLE rule_repositories;
DROP TABLE organizations;
DROP TABLE webhook_deliveries;
```

I executed these DDL statements on the prod instance and the upgrade was successful.  Thank you all for your suggestions.  They pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Downgrade SonarQube is not supported. You should start with an empty database or install a database backup with the correct SonarQube version.

Comment: Not to split hairs, but the downgrade, in this case, worked fine for almost 18 months.  It was when I attempted to upgrade the SonarQube instance again that I ran into problems. I'm not saying it's a bug, it was definitely an oversight on my part.  Of course, if the SonarSource folks would stop breaking plugins when they make changes to their architecture, we wouldn't have had to downgrade our instance in the first place. ;P

Comment: I'm getting this same issue with my upgrade from version 6.5 to 6.7 in my case I needed to run the following commands:
drop table ce_task_characteristics;
drop table plugins;
drop table project_branches;
drop table qprofile_edit_users;
drop table qprofile_edit_groups;
drop table analysis_properties;

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade to the latest 5.X LTS version before you upgrade to 6.X LTS.

The latest 5.X LTS version is 5.6.7 (see [release notes](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10930&version=13778)), so first you have to upgrade 5.6.5 to 5.6.7 and next to 6.7.

Comment: That sounded like a great suggestion, and while the upgrade from 5.6.5 to 5.6.7 went off without a hitch, I'm getting the same error when upgrading from 5.6.7 to 6.7.  I appreciate the input though.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when upgrading from 6.5 to 6.7. Seems like SonarQube simply needs to add some logic to their upgrade scripts so that they don't fail if a table already exists.